# TypeError: text.toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'text.toLowerCase()', 'text.toLowerCase' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a project using MERN STACK in this I faced the above error.

**ProductContainer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Icon, Item, Input } from 'native-base';
import ProductList from './ProductList';
import SearchedProduct from './SearchedProducts';

const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');
const ProductContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

        setProducts(data);
        setProductsFiltered(data);
        setFocus(false);

        return () => {
            setProducts([])
            setProductsFiltered([])
            setFocus()
        }

    }, [])

    const SearchProduct = (text) => {

        setProductsFiltered(
            products.filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
        );

    };

    const openList = () => {
        setFocus(true);
    };

    const onBlur = () => {
        setFocus(flase);
    };

    return (

        <Container>
            <View  style = {{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                  <Input
                  width = "100%"
                  variant = "rounded"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  onFocus={openList}
                  onChangeText={(text) => SearchProduct(text)}
                  />
            </View>

            {focus == true ? (

                <SearchProduct 
                    productsFiltered={productsFiltered}
                />

            ) : (

                <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Product Container</Text>
                <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={products}
                        numColumns={2}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <ProductList 
                        key={item.brand}
                        item={item}/>}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.brand}
                    />
                </View>

            </View> 

        )}

        </Container>

    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },

  });

export default ProductContainer
```

**SearchedProducts.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import { Content, Left, Body, ListItem, Thumbnail, Text } from 'native-base';
const SearchedProduct = (props) => {
    const { productsFiltered } = props;
    return(
        <Content >
            {productsFiltered.length > 0 ? (
                productsFiltered.map((item) => (
                    <ListItem
                        key={item._id.$oid}
                        avatar
                    >
                        <Left>
                            <Thumbnail 
                                source={{uri: item.image ? 
                                    item.image : 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/01/17/29/box-23649_960_720.png'
                                        }}
                            />
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text note>{item.description}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>
                ))
            ) : (
                <View style={styles.center}>
                    <Text style={{ alignSelf:  'center' }}>
                        No products match the selected criteria
                    </Text>
                </View>
            )}
        </Content>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    center: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 100
    }
})

export default SearchedProduct;
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this error .If you want I will provide other details of my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you are using SearchProduct name as a component and at the same time as a method. Maybe try to rename changing either component name or method name to see if it works.

Comment: I tried your solution @Tarik but the error is not solved. Can you please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Please update your code with the attempt you tried. Then we can see clearly where is the issue. I still can see that you import `SearchedProduct` but you used as `<SearchProduct/>` which looks not correct.

Comment: Hello @Tarik I had updated my code .Can you please visit the link https://snack.expo.dev/@naheeda24/animal-feedmart. And after modifying the code I am facing the "Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. ".Can you please explain the error and modify the code .